# how to use javascript variable in model query razor

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

```
  function SetPrice(id, name, price) {

    var selectdePackage=@Model.PackageList.Where(x => x.Id == id).ToList()

    debugger;
    if(name=="Trial")
    {
        debugger;
        alert("You Not Select Trial Package Please Select Other Package.");
        return;
    }
    if($('#'+id).text()=="Current package")
    {
        debugger;
        alert(" Alredy Your Current package Select  . ");
        return;

    }
```

}

i want to use javascript variable in model lambda expretion  but it not access in query and store all list of data in variale and other error is syntest  error anyone know  how it work

Comment: `var selectdePackage = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.PackageList.Where(x => x.Id == id)))'`, but nowhere in your code do you ever access it so not clear what your doing this for.

Comment: @StephenMuecke....OP is using `id` which is a javascript variable in linq statement..which is not possible...

Comment: @Kartikeya, Didn't notice `id` was a javascript variable :). Would then need to remove the `.Where()` and use a javascript loop to access the value

Comment: ya id is javascript variable  it  is possible to access?

Comment: @jayeshdhameliya...NO..you can't use javascript variable inside linq statement as shown in your question..because server side code executed much before javascript code...you have to use some workaround.

Comment: @jayeshdhameliya, You can assign the whole collection to a javascript array using `var packages = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.PackageList)'`, and then you can use a loop ('for` or `$.each()) or `$.filter()` to get the object that matches the `Id`, but its not clear why since you never use the value of `selectdePackage`

Comment: i was display all package and  client select some  package  if  client select alredy one package then client not select down gread package price  so  i wanto find alredy selecte package bt client

Comment: thank you all  plz  i  want another help      i was use two    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ReferenceNumber, new { @class = "form-control input-sm", required = "", placeholder = "Receipt Number" })  one  is hide and one is show using jquery  but  in my controller  first   text value ony  get  when i use second  text box  value is null  plz help  me   i am new in mvc

Comment: If you have another problem, then you need to ask another question